# GAE version-project-id.appspot.com works but not project-id.appspot.com

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I deployed sample node.js application on GAE.

From admin console, under version i can see my 'version-project-id.appspot.com' url and able to access it also. 
This is the only version which is deployed and serving.

However when I access 'project-id.appspot.com' url, I get 404 error.

Doesn't project-id.appspot.com url automatically points to latest and promoted version-project-id.appspot.com url?

Is there any other setting to do to make this work?

Comment: How exactly did you deploy that version?

Comment: Using gcloud app deploy command

Comment: Which can do things in several different ways: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_your_program

Comment: I still didn't get how to access project-id.appspot.com

Comment: I tried with gcloud app services set-traffic --splits <version>=1 also..then also unable to get desired version as default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally deleted that particular project and created a new one, re-deployed app in it. It worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you go to:

https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions?project={project-id}&moduleId=default

and set the default to the version you want.

Comment: Where is the option to make any one version as default? When i select a version i just see following options on the top menu : start , stop , migrate traffic, split traffic etc..

Comment: I selected a version and clicked on 'migrate traffic' to 100%. After doing that, URL does get pointed to project-id.appspot.com. However now if click on the URL, i still get 404 error and if i refresh the admin console page, setting of migrate to 100% clears off. Any help here on these 2 problems?

Comment: It can take a few minutes:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/migrating-traffic

Comment: Atleast the setting of 'migrate to 100%' should get saved. On refresh of console that setting clears off. Is this a bug in such a basic operation?

Comment: I have never seen it do that.  When you hit "Migrate traffic", a pop up box comes up.  Hit the "More" link there, and check the box to force the traffic.  Then, hit "Migrate"

Comment: I did exactly the same...in console-> versions, progress bar under column 'traffic allocation' shows 100% for selected app version. Now if click on refresh on the top, this setting goes away..

Comment: Do you see a message at bottom left of window, saying "migrating traffic" or  "routing all traffic..." or "... in progress"?

Comment: Yes i do see this dialog, once it goes away i can see 100% allocation to selected version. But the moment i refresh the console, this setting goes away. Could this be dues to node.js runtime env which is still in beta mode? This operation is very simple.

Comment: What do you see at: https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/services?project={project-id}&moduleId=default ?  If you are using `gcloud app deploy`, it should automatically update the version, and make it default.

Comment: Here I see just 1 entry..'default' which is pointing to project-id.appspot.com..have to check if this is really pointing to the selected version. Nevertheless clicking on the same is also yielding 404 error. Deployment was done using gcloud app deploy command only.

Comment: I tried CLI also as gcloud app services set-traffic --splits <myversion>=1...then also i dont see 100% of traffic going to this version even though command is successfully executed.

Answer (score 1):

Right now your service is not set as default. For that just change service in your `app.yaml` file to be `default`. It will start serving that service on `project-id.appspot.com`

The design of server-side should be:

```
default service: controller for other services
  - service 1
  - service 2
```

Comment: app.yaml has following entries: 'runtime: node.js vm: true' . In console -> versions, i can see 2 versions deployed, out of which 1 should be default when someone hits project-id.appspot.com. In console-> services i see only 1 entry named as 'default'...are you suggesting to put following line in app.yaml  'module: default'?

Comment: Yes! Though module is being deprecated and you should use `service: default`

Comment: Tried this, still not working ...when i hit project.appspot.com url, I see following in browser                                                                                                                                  'Error: Not Found
The requested URL / was not found on this server.' version.project.appspot.com works fine..

Comment: my app.yaml has following entries now runtime:node.js vm:true service:default

Comment: just for the sake of brevity can you try running the sample nodejs app? https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/hello-world

Comment: i have been trying this sample only. the only difference is that i have 3 versions of the same app running now. all visible under console->versions. under console->service i see one entry as default with versions 3. All individual versions-project-id-appsport urls are working but not project-id-appsport url. tried migrating traffic also to 100% to any one version thru UI and CLI. Commands get executed successfully but on refresh don't see 100% split getting persisted against selected version. No able to figure out what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: any more suggestion or help here?